# Simulation of the Micro-kinetic generator

Tags: simulation, generator, simulink, energy-harvesting

I am simulating the [block diagram of the Autoquartz system during unwinding](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224142807_Micro-kinetic_Generator_Modeling_Energy_Conversion_Optimization_and_Design_Considerations) in Simulink.

I want to get the current of microgenerator (Ibus), 
but I get an oscillating pattern, which you can see here [image: here].

[image] This is the bock diagram I simulated for Tdmax = 8. Please help me how to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's not intended behavior?  And if it isn't, could you please simplify the block diagram down to something that just shows the functional elements, without all of the oscilloscope blocks, or perhaps highlight the actual functional signal path?

Comment: @TimWescott, Thank for your reply. I edited the post and change the block diagram. I expect to get a discent pattern for the current.

Comment: A "decent pattern" for the current?  Define decent -- I assume you mean smooth and continuous, but I see no reason to assume that's what's desired.

Comment: You really need to post figure 6 from the paper, too -- or annotate your diagram with their annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In their Figure 6, they are not modeling the rectification.  They are showing the armature current as being equal to (armature EMF - bus voltage)/(overall resistance) -- but this is not correct.  Under rectification, the current would only flow when the armature EMF exceeds the bus voltage.

So in between the summation block with the bus voltage, and the "1/R" block, you need a block that implements rectification: $$e_{out} = \begin{cases}
0 & e_{in} < 0 \\
e_{in} & e_{in} \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Either that, or you want to move the \$|x|\$ block into that spot, rather than just feeding an oscilloscope with it (and you want to remove it from the oscilloscope feed).